# Can't get model's value

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to make a simple login function with angular, so when I finished typing in username and password, I want to check the return values(the username and password) but it didn't work, nothing was called when I hit the login button. I've already imported the FormsModule to "app.module.ts". This is what I have so far:

in login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html'
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {} ;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
}
login() {
   console.log(this.model);
  }
}
```

in login.component.html:

```
 <form #loginForm="ngForm" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" (ngSumbit)="login()">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="username"  
     placeholder="Username" required [(ngModel)]="model.username" >

    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" name="password" 
     placeholder="Password" required [(ngModel)]="model.password"  >

    <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0"  type="submit">Login</button>
 </form>
```

please help.

Comment: Add something like this onto `<button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0"  type="submit" (click)="login()">Login</button>` ?

Comment: yeah, but I believe ngSubmit and submit did the same thing in this situation, turns out It was my mistake, I typed the wrong word("ngSumbit" ) :^)

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo:

```
(ngSumbit)="login()"
     ^^
```

it should be ngSu**bm**it

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much !!!! It took me 3 hours to figure it out :-)